# Web based application to edit documents

Tags: web-applications

I have a directory online with a few documents that my engineers on the field can pull down. I need them to be able to edit the files and publish them back on the directory. What is the easiest technology I can use to build a web application where they can submit the files back onto the webserver or possibly even edit the files directly in the browser?

I am familiar with mySQL & ASP.net but if something simpler can be used please explain.

Answer (score 0):

For online inline editing, if you're just looking for a drop-in technology to do the trick (which is probably the best idea, as something custom would be a potentially huge investment), then the only options that come to mind right away are:

- [SharePoint](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/Pages/default.aspx) (with MS Office on the client for the editing)
- [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/)